# MFMessageComposeViewController will not present in form sheet on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

If I run this code on an iPad (iOS 8) from a view controller:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get a fullscreen message composition view.  But I see no documentation or reference anywhere of `MFMessageComposeViewController` ignoring its modal presentation style.  Is this expected? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Faced a similar issue recently targeting iOS8. It does seem like `MFMessageComposeViewController` ignores the modalPresentationStyle property. Strangely enough `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't seem to have this issue. Anyways, to resolve it, I embedded the `MFMessageComposeViewController` inside a UIViewController and presented that instead. Below is the code to accomplish this:

```
var messageViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self

let containerViewController = UIViewController()
containerViewController.view.addSubview(messageViewController.view)
messageViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
containerViewController.addChildViewController(messageViewController)
messageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController) 

containerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
containerViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
presentViewController(containerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Successfully applied modal presentation in such way.
It`s just unclear why you use nil in 
"messageViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)"